# Battery connectors like smartphone

Tags: batteries

I've a question about how are made batteries connector of smartphones. I've tried to find images of an opened battery, but with no result.  In particular this image:

[image]

This connector is a module? How it's soldered internally?

Also, It can be a pcb attached to plastic with gold plated pads?(or in case of no, it's possible to do something like this or will result unreliable contacts?)

EDIT:
I mean gold pads on PCB and not on plastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a small PCB containing the battery protection circuit. The PCB is moulded into the plastic. I have never seen a gold (plated) contact on plastic. I don't think it can be done, you need something stronger like PCb material. Also see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uI1eRy0uBI8).

Comment: Thank's for your video. But there is something still not clear to me. That pads on PCB are something like special manufacturing with some kind of surface finish? Or just gold plated? I ask this becouse they seems very shiny.

Comment: I think they're just gold plated, nothing special going on :-) Perhaps there are different ways of gold plating which can give either a nice and shiny surface or one that is less shiny. Perhaps they simply polished it to make it shiny in this case.

Comment: http://pimg.tradeindia.com/01615889/b/1/Blackberry-8700-PCB.jpg like this